# Can I Develop Blazor MAUI project with Connecting the ObjectDataSource Component to a Data Source in Telerik Report?

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, maui, telerik-reporting

I Need to develop the Blazor MAUI project with the Telerik Report in that project stored. Also, that report needs to be created with Connecting DataObjectSource.

1. I want to know how to develop a report connecting DataObjectSource.
2. How to add that report to the MAUI project with Configuration.

Can you help me with an example?
Thank You!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Telerik resources. They refer to sample projects from the Telerik Reporting samples repo:

- [Telerik Reporting in .NET MAUI and .NET MAUI Blazor](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/displaying-telerik-report-in-net-maui-and-maui-blazor-applications)
- [Telerik Reporting Conquers .NET MAUI and .NET MAUI Blazor](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-reporting-conquers-dotnet-maui-blazor)
- [Display Telerik Reports in the Telerik Blazor PDF Viewer in a Hybrid .NET MAUI Blazor Application](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/display-reports-in-maui-blazor-pdf-viewer)

The [ObjectDataSource component](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/connecting-to-data/data-source-components/objectdatasource-component/overview) assembly is resolved by the Reporting engine. You need to reference the assembly providing the data to the project hosting the Reporting engine and register the assembly in its configuration file - [Configuration](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/connecting-to-data/data-source-components/objectdatasource-component/connecting-the-objectdatasource-component-to-a-data-source#configuration) section from the article [Connecting the ObjectDataSource Component to a Data Source](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/connecting-to-data/data-source-components/objectdatasource-component/connecting-the-objectdatasource-component-to-a-data-source). An example is available in the Telerik Reporting demos deployed with the installation.